# Can we mount EFS on AWS ECS docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I have an ECS instance on which my docker containers are running. I want to mount EFS on docker container which is running on ECS. Is it possible then how?

I am able to mount EFS on ECS instance but not on docker container which is running on ECS.

EFS is with direct connect & able to telnet it on 2049 port from docker.

**mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 X.X.X.X:/ /efs**

**Error is :- mount.nfs4: Operation not permitted**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should part of your task definition, you need to add the volumes in the task definition and then refer it in the source volume option, here is a tutorial from AWS.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-to-persist-data-from-amazon-ecs-containers/

```
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "efs",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/mnt/efs/mysql"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you  @Sudharsan. i have successfully configured it . i got the hint and proper workaround from your answer.                                                                           REF URL :-  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_efs.html

Comment: NOTE: The above configuration only works for EC2 launch types on ECS. For Fargate, you have to use efsVolumeConfiguration

Answer (score 21):

## Update; Jan 17 2020 - Preview ECS/EFS Support

On January 17 2020 AWS [announced an preview for ECS support for EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/amazon-ecs-preview-support-for-efs-file-systems-now-available). It is important to note that this is currently a *preview release*; see information on what that means in the [configuration documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_EFSVolumeConfiguration.html).

Instead of defining volumes and all of their connection parameters, you may simply define the new `EFSVolumeConfiguration` object.

```
"EFSVolumeConfiguration": {
  "fileSystemId": "fs-xxxxxx",
  "rootDirectory": "/mnt/volume/path"
}
```

## Original Answer

As of August 2018, with docker volume support, you can now [mount NFS shares directly into an ECS container](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/amazon-ecs-now-supports-docker-volume-and-volume-plugins/).

The documentation which is available currently does not detail how to use EFS with ECS via docker volume, however it is possible.

### Configuring the docker volume

First, include a `volumes` section in your task configuration similar to the following:

```
"volumes": [
   {
     "name": "efs",
     "host": null,
     "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
       "autoprovision": null,
       "labels": null,
       "scope": "task",
       "driver": "local",
       "driverOpts": {
         "type": "nfs",
         "device": ":/",
         "o": "addr=<fs-id>.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport"
       }
     }
   }
]
```

Ensure that you update the `addr` parameter inside the `o` option to match your EFS filesystem's DNS name.

Then, include this volume in a mount in one of your container definitions. For more information on the syntax, see [Docker Volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html).

```
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "sourceVolume": "efs",
                "containerPath": "/path/to/mount_volume",
                "readOnly": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The configuration options being used for the NFS connection are the ones recommended at time of writing by AWS for [Mounting EFS filesystems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html).

Comment: I wish I could give you more up-votes for this one. Awesome!

Comment: does this work for task definitions that are auto-generated by AWS Batch? AFAIK no.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**
When you want to mount the EFS to EC2 instance and then make all the containers to use it.
Run below command to mount the EFS to the EC2 instance.

```
sudo mount -t efs fs-0ad7c287c2f7c27c2 /mnt/efs
```

Then reference it in the task-definition as sourcePath so the container can use the efs mount path as the writable layer.

```
"volumes": [
 {
  "name": "efs",
  "host": {
    "sourcePath": "/mnt/efs/mysql"
   }
 }
]
```

**Approach 2:**
When auto-scaling is enabled on ECS, it's good to attach the EFS volume directly to the ECS task/container.
In task-definition mention like below so the containers will directly mount the EFS upon spawn.

```
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "Tiger-Test",
        "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
        "fileSystemId": "fs-0ad7c287c2f7c27c2"
        }
    }
]
```